# Difference between "elsif" and "if" inside of "else"

Tags: ruby

```
class Player
  def play_turn(warrior)
    if warrior.feel.enemy?
       warrior.attack!
        else
          if warrior.health < 20 && !taking_damage?(warrior)
            warrior.rest!
      else
        warrior.walk!
      end
    end
    @health = warrior.health
  end


  def taking_damage?(warrior)
    warrior.health < @health
  end

end
```

What does it mean if there comes "if" inside of "else" like in the above code? And how does it differ from "elsif" as in

```
class Player
  def play_turn(warrior)
   if warrior.feel.enemy?
     warrior.walk!
   elsif warrior.health <= 10
   else warrior.attack!
   end
end
```

?

As far as I know "elsif" is used for additional conditions, and I am having hard time understanding the "if inside of else" pattern in the first example code. I would appreciate any help!

The first code example above is from https://gist.github.com/rantingsonrails/3035155.

Comment: Your two code are expressing different things. For example, `< 20` and `<= 10` are obviously different. If you want to ask the difference with respect to a certain point, make them minimally different, showing your point.

Comment: Each `if` requires an `end` and optionally includes one or more `elsif`'s and one `else`.  Start with one of the innermost `if-end` constructs.  Remove it.  Now look at another innermost `if-end` construct (which may not have been innermost before the first one was removed).  Remove it. Continue until you have just the outer construct.  That tells you what you need to know.  You need to reformat `play_turn` to show the correct structure.  That method has 12 lines.  Those lines should be indented fhe following number of spaces: 2, 4, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 6, 4, 4, 2. (You should do an edit.)

Answer (score 0):

If inside of else means, only if the first if isn't true, then continue with this if.

In the case of the code above, the check for the health being less than 20 etc. would only occur if there were no enemy in the vicinity.

And there is no difference between an if inside of else and elsif, except that elsif doesn't require extra indentation and therefore saves space.